# Get last added value of boost accumulator_set

Tags: c++, boost, accumulator

I am using `boost::accumulator_set` to compute the min, max and mean of some values.

Is there a way (`perhaps a boost::accumulators::tag`) to retrieve the last value that was fed to the accumulator? Something like `boost::accumulators::last(my_acc)`?

Comment: A thing you can try is remixing one of the simpler tags like `min` to make your own. If it works, great, if not, you will have some code for your question.

Comment: I don't think last is ever statistically relevant. Also nothing stops you from recording the last sample, without requiring the feature from accumulator_set

Comment: It surely is not statistically relevant, but I frequently need it and such a solution would make my code look cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

You could hack it using a rolling window size==1:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83455d7d1f421fdf)**

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_sum.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_window.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
namespace ba  = boost::accumulators;
namespace bat = boost::accumulators::tag;

int main() {
    ba::accumulator_set<double, ba::stats<bat::mean, bat::rolling_window, bat::rolling_sum>> accu(
        bat::rolling_window::window_size = 1);

    for (int i : {100, 10, 50, -70}) {
        accu(i);
        fmt::print("mean {:>6.2f} last {:>6.2f} (total #{} samples)\n", ba::mean(accu), ba::rolling_sum(accu),
                   ba::count(accu));
    }
}
```

Print

```
mean 100.00 last 100.00 (total #1 samples)
mean  55.00 last  10.00 (total #2 samples)
mean  53.33 last  50.00 (total #3 samples)
mean  22.50 last -70.00 (total #4 samples)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. 
In the mean time I've implemented such  a feature myself, mostly copying the existing 'sum' feature and changing '+=' to '=' 
Link to original: https://github.com/boostorg/accumulators/blob/develop/include/boost/accumulators/statistics/sum.hpp

Comment: Consider posting your own answer so it may help others. And so we can vote it up (hint :))

Answer (score 1):

I've found an easy way to implement this feature: Simply write a new feature by copying the existing 'sum' feature ([link to original](https://github.com/boostorg/accumulators/blob/develop/include/boost/accumulators/statistics/sum.hpp)) and changing '+=' to '='. This does the job.